# regex for not matching

Tags: regex

I have several strings like this

```
+My_name
My_other_name
+Someone
Otherone
```

Whats the regex to write to get me all strings that do not begin with the + symbol

I need the result to include

```
My_other_name
OtherOne
```

Comment: Sorry i overlooked this seems to do it ^[\+]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[^\+].+$
```

1. ^ = Anchor beginning of line
2. [^\+] = exclude lines beginning with the plus, and is escaped with a slash so not to confuse the regex.
3. . = any character
4. - = repeat any number of times
5. $ = Anchor end of line.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest is probably:

```
^[^+].*
```

Working example: http://rubular.com/r/zzNeuvqKFB

You can drop the `.*` if you `grep` the file anyway.
Of course, all programming languages should have a better way of getting these lines. Even grep has the `-v` flag, to negate the pattern.

Comment: Thanks Kobi for taking time out on this

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on what program you are using, but something like `^[^+]+`.